# loop through multiple classes

Tags: c++, class, loops, iterator

in my code there are several classes

```
class samples{
some_public_variables
} a, b, c;
```

I want to ask if there is any way to loop through all these classes, something like this

```
for(i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++){
    class[i].variable.do_something   }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: No there isn't. Now, what is the real problem here. No, not the one you're asking about, but the one for which you think the solution is what you're asking about, here.

Comment: ok! thank you! i will try to think a different approach!

Comment: There is only one class in your code, there are three variables which are instances of the class.

Comment: Do you mean something like this class samples{} a[3];?  This seems to work with g++ and clang++, but I've never seen it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like:

```
class samples{
    void foo() const;
};

samples a, b, c;

for (const auto& s : { std::ref(a), std::ref(b), std::ref(c) }) {
    s.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...or equally horrid...

```
int main()
{
    class samples{
    public:
        samples(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
        int x, y , z;
    }
    a { 1, 2, 3 },
    b { 4, 5, 6},
    c { 7, 8, 9 };

    for (auto& s : { &a, &b, &c })
    {
        std::cout << s->x << " " << s->y << " " << s->z << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate different classes that do the same action, use polymorphism to accomplish that. You can create an abstract class to create an interface for your other classes, as this:

```cpp
class MyInterface {

    public:
        /* Common method that must be implemented by all children classes */
        virtual void doSomething() = 0;
 };
```

And then you implement the specific method for each of your classes.

```
class MyClassA : public MyInterface {

    public:
        void doSomething() { /* Implementation for class A */ }
};

class MyClassB : public MyInteface {

    public:
        void doSomething() { /* Implementation for class B */ }
};
```

After that you can iterate your classes using the common interface and calling the common method. Like that:

```cpp
std::vector<MyInterface> classes;
// Fill your vector with instances of your classes.
for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); ++i) {
    classes.doSomething();
}
```

Hope that helps you with your problem.